# What's the best SE place to ask if some computer science theory proposals have been successfully applied in commercial systems?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm thinking e.g. that four-valued or even more generally bilattice-valued logics and reasoning systems have been touted in a number of logic and CS papers. I want to ask if these have found any success in a commercial system.

What's the best SE place to ask something like that, i.e. if some computer science theory proposals have been successfully applied in commercial systems?

Comment: Perhaps: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ not a site I know about though, so do read the help before you post.